# navigation bar onclick not adding the class using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

In my navigation bar , I need a class "active" to be added in the navigation bar list. My problem is after adding the class page is refreshing and the active class is hiding again.Please help.I am not knowing what to do.

HTML

```
<div class="navigation_part">
    <div id="top-nav">
        <ul>    
            <li class=""><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>                       
            <li class=""><a href="about.php">About&nbsp;Us</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="entrepreneurs.php">Entrepreneurs</a></li>         
            <li class=""><a href="investors.php">Investors</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="contactus.php">Contact&nbsp;Us</a></li>   
        </ul>   
        <div class="nav_bar_underline"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// I tried these both but both not working
$('.navigation_part li').on('click', function() {
$(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
$('.navigation_part li a').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action
e.stopPropagation; // stop the click from bubbling
$('.navigation_part li').removeClass('current');
$(this).parent().addClass('current');
});  });
```

if i use `preventDefault()` href of the anchor is not working...

Comment: check this it is working fine http://jsfiddle.net/ef694/

Comment: If you click on anchor it's obvious the page will be reloaded. Do you want the links to be working or the page to **not** reload?

Comment: check you browser console may be this show what is error in your Jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done better with php
Do the following

In each pages  like index.php, contactus.php,aboutus.php... add this code at the top

```
  <?php $page= basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    include ("header.php");
     ?>
```

### header.php  modified

```
<div class="navigation_part">
    <div id="top-nav">
        <ul>    
            <li class="<?php echo ($page == "index.php" ? "active" : "")?>"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>                       
            <li class="<?php echo ($page == "about.php" ? "active" : "")?>"><a href="about.php">About&nbsp;Us</a></li>
            <li class="<?php echo ($page == "entrepreneurs.php" ? "active" : "")?>"><a href="entrepreneurs.php">Entrepreneurs</a></li>         
            <li class="<?php echo ($page == "investors.php" ? "active" : "")?>"><a href="investors.php">Investors</a></li>
            <li class="<?php echo ($page == "contactus.php" ? "active" : "")?>"><a href="contactus.php">Contact&nbsp;Us</a></li>   
        </ul>   
        <div class="nav_bar_underline"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i want to add the class "active" to the navigation bar(li). But for me if class is added, href is not working.. and if onclick href works, class is not adding! not knowing what is the problem

Comment: @Supriya , if href work then the page navigates to other page, then how the current page is displayed with your navigation bar .

Comment: Hope you understood what I meant, You have to paste this navigation url in each page like index.php,contactus.php,..etc,and keep the corresponding 'li' of the page to be active,This is the method that works

Comment: im using header.php for all the pages.. so according to u wat should i do tell me..

Comment: oh you have used separate php page for header right..ok I will explain to you

Comment: Thanku @sarath it worked.. actually i'm new to php.. what does this mean "$page= basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);"..?

Answer (score 2):

Any changes made with JavaScript to the current page will be lost when you navigate to another page. The browser doesn't automatically apply the changes to the menu on the other page (which is a *different* menu by all counts.)

Unless you have some dynamic system that captures the clicks and changes the page content with AJAX, but it seems unlikely.

The easiest way to achieve what you probably need is to do it server-side, and since you seem to be using PHP:

```
<li class="<?php if( __FILE__ === "index.php" ) echo "actuve"; ?>"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li> 
<li class="<?php if( __FILE__ === "about.php" ) echo "active"; ?>"><a href="about.php">About&nbsp;Us</a></li> 
...etc
```

Comment: I want the class name to be added to the navigation bar. But its not happening.